# HVAC Adding a Common

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

[image]

Got a new Honeywell WiFi thermostat and need to add a common.  Currently the 3 common wires per the diagram (BL, BK, GY) are wired to one side of the AC Unit.  Is there an issue if I piggy back a common off those wires (add a new wire to the wire nutted bundle).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Go for it man

That's precisely the right move in your case -- that's where the system wiring diagram expects you to tap your C wire at.